# Android image size confusion

Tags: android, xamarin, android-imageview, android-image, dpi

I'm very confused about making drawables for Android.
Let's say I want to make a big image that will fill 30% of the screen, or a certain amount of dp, like 300dp.
What size should that image be in pixels for each screen density, and in what dpi should I save it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 300dp, you need:

300px for mdpi (1x)

450px for hdpi (1.5x)

600px for xhdpi (2x)

900px for xxhdpi (3x)

1200px for xxxhdpi (4x)

Comment: Thanks. And what will the dpi be? I saw that Google's icons are always 96 dpi.

Comment: you need to see which drawable folder you are looking into , every drawable folder will have different sizes

Comment: All of the icons in each of the drawable folders have the same dpi. Have a look at one of the icons here: https://design.google.com/icons/index.html

Comment: once i click on some icon i get an option to select png or Svg.

Comment: once i click on some icon i get an option to select png or Svg in the link you have given.
1) SVG are vector graphics these images are basically doesnt need to be in different resolutions they will scale .
2) Png images on the other hand to be supplied in various resoultions from mdpi till xxxhdpi

Comment: Look at the pngs Vertical resolutions and you'll see that they are all 96 dpi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123723/discussion-between-surya-and-amitairos).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

ldpi    -    0.75 * mdpi ,
mdpi    -    1    * mdpi ,
hdpi    -    1.5  * mdpi ,
xhdpi   -    2    * mdpi ,
xxhdpi  -    3    * mdpi ,
xxxhdpi -    4    * hdpi ,

so if you want to generate for mdpi screen to be 300dp the image should be resized according to the above calculation